# Is there a difference between the PositiveReals set and the NonNegativeReals set?

Tags: pyomo

I am wondering if there are any differences between the predefined PositiveReals and NonNegativeReals sets.

I have read the documentation on predefined sets but I can't find the difference explicitly stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-negative reals include 0.

Positive reals do not include 0.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I thought but I wasn't sure